# Verifying existing users in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website that saves user data on the local storage. it works well, but I wrote an if else statement to handle people signing up with existing email. I do not know why the code doesn't work. I created a variable duplicateUsers followed by the if else statement. below are the HTML CSS and javascript code.

the javascript file does the following
1) adds a user to the local storage by clicking the signup button
2) checks for incomplete details
3) checks for duplicate users and performs an action based on the response (doesn't work)

the problem here is that regardless of whether the user already exists, it still adds the user to the local storage instead of returning an alert saying the user already exists.

```js
var signUpBtn = document.querySelector('#signUp');
var signUpOver = document.querySelector('.signup__overlay');

var signInBtn = document.querySelector('#signIn');
var signInOver = document.querySelector('.signin__overlay');

var fullname = document.querySelector('#name');
var email = document.querySelector('#email');
var password = document.querySelector('#password');
var age = document.querySelector('#age');
var occupation = document.querySelector('#occupation');
var address = document.querySelector('#address');

var signupSubmitClicked = document.querySelector('#signupClicked'); 





signupSubmitClicked.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fullname.value=="" || email.value=="" || password.value=="" || age.value=="" || occupation.value=="" || address.value=="") {
    alert("incomplete datails, please fill up everything")
  } else {
    alert("item created")
    addUser(fullname, email, password, age,  occupation, address);
  }
});


var addUser = (fullname, email, password, age,  occupation, address) => {
  var users = [];
  const user = {
    fullname: fullname.value,
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value,
    age: age.value,
    occupation: occupation.value,
    address: address.value
  };


  try {
    var existingUsers = localStorage.getItem('userData');
    users = JSON.parse(existingUsers) || [];
  } catch (e) {

  }

  var duplicateUsers = users.filter(user => user.email === email);
  
  if (duplicateUsers.length === 0) {
    users.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(users));
  } else {
    alert("user already exists");
  }

};



/*************
signup popup
*************/
signUpBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  signUpOver.style.display = 'block';
});

signUpOver.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(event.target == signUpOver){
    signUpOver.style.display = "none";
  }
});
/*************
signup popup
*************/


/*************
signin popup
*************/
signInBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  signInOver.style.display = 'block';
});

signInOver.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(event.target == signInOver){
    signInOver.style.display = "none";
  }
});
/*************
signin popup
*************/
/** the end */
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F8F9F9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#mainPage,
#userPage {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#userPage {
  display: none;
}

/********************
overlay
********************/
.signup__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.signup__content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.signin__overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.signin__content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}


/********************
overlay ending
********************/

.headerMain {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.headerUser {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.upButton {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upButton, .inButton {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: #239B56;
  border: #239B56;
  color: snow;
}

label {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

label,
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>User system</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="mainPage">

      <div class="signup__overlay">
        <div class="signup__content">
          <form>
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="name">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input required type="text" id="email" name="email">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input required type="password" id="password" name="password">

            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input required type="text" id="age" name="age">

            <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
            <input required type="text" id="occupation" name="occupation">

            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input required type="text" id="address" name="address">

            <input type="submit" id="signupClicked">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="signin__overlay">
        <div class="signin__content">
          <form>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input required type="text" id="Email" name="email">

            <label for="email">Password</label>
            <input required type="Password" id="Password" name="Password">

            <input type="submit" id="signinClicked">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>


    <header class="headerMain">User System</header>
    <section>
        <button class="upButton" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>

        <button class="inButton" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div id="userPage">

      <header class="headerUser">User System</header>
      <section>
          
      </section>
  
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please break down this wall-o-code to the important bits. We are no debuggers,

Comment: Not sure, but in your `addUser()` function you are filtering duplicates array `var duplicateUsers = users.filter(user => user.email === email);` I believe your `email` variable refers to the Element object, not the value, thus, your duplicates are always empty

Comment: @LudovitMydlaI am sorry, I don't understand. The user.email which is the value inputted is being compared with the previously stored values.

Comment: @wayneOS the important part which isn't working is    `var duplicateUsers = users.filter(user => user.email === email);
  
  if (duplicateUsers.length === 0) {
    users.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(users));
  } else {
    alert("user already exists");
  }`

Comment: @OpeyemiOdedeyi i think you need to check against `email.value` not `email` in your filter.